# Session with mod_rewrite

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

iam using mod-rewrite to create human readable urls. (POST: [Mod rewrite - make link readable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10631829/mod-rewrite-make-link-readable))

Now i have a problem. I am using sessions. how can i forward the session id??

My .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.de$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.de$1 [R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.html$ /?lang=$1&subid=$2&id=$3 [L]
```

My idea was to change it that way:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.html?+(.*)+$ /?lang=$1&subid=$2&id=$3&$4 [L]
```

But that doesnt work.

Best regards

Answer (score 1):

The `RewriteRule` removes the query string including any session ID. You need to add the `QSA` flag (query string append):

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.html$ /?lang=$1&subid=$2&id=$3 [L,QSA]
```

This will preserve your session ID.

Comment: Well...didnt change anything :-(

Comment: I can't see any problem... Did you try using Session-Cookies instead of appending the ID to the query string?